# How do i add a page to a web template

Tags: application-pages, web-template

I have created a basic web template using the following post and added a custom list to it, this works fine.  http://sebastiantegel.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/webtemplates-is-the-way-to-go/

I now want to add a screen/page to the web template which will show this list and also 2 visual web parts, the nav bars on the left should link to the page (i know how to do this part).

I am a new sharepoint developer.

I need to add a page to the web template which will show a list and also 2 custom visual web parts.

How do i do this in visual studio (it has to be done in visual studio)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the file in the webtemplates folder, then add it into the onet.xml to be created when you make the site.

Files get added to the onet file near the bottom, you can see the layout:

```
<Module Name="myfile" Url="" Path="">
  <File Url="myfile.aspx" NavBarHome="True" Type="Ghostable"/>
</Module>
```

It's as simple as that.